# What does: "Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled” error mean?

Tags: database, postgresql

In my program, I’ve got several threads in pool that each try to write to the DB. The number of threads created is dynamic. When the number of threads created is only one, all works fine. However, when there are multi-thread executing, I get the error:

`org.apache.ddlutils.DatabaseOperationException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.`

I’m guessing, perhaps since each thread executes in parallel, two threads are trying to write at the same time and giving this error.

Do you think this is the case, if not, what could be causing this error?

Otherwise, if what I said is the problem, what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your jdbc code, you should turn off autocommit as soon as you fetch the connection. Something like this:

```
DataSource datasource = getDatasource(); // fetch your datasource somehow
Connection c = null;
try{
  c = datasource.getConnection();
  c.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: thnx this works.. but could you perhaps explain why this works, and if there is any disadvantage this way?!

Comment: Sure. Autocommit is a database connection setting that automatically begin and commits a databse transaction whenever a DML statement (UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE) is executed. This simplifies certain programming tasks and reduces the required boilerplate for simple db operations. However, if you are running multiple dependent statements and you want to make sure they all succeed (i.e. if any of them fail or throw an exception then none of them take effect) you will need to turn autocommit off and manually begin/commit the transactions yyourself, which is also more efficient.

Comment: ok, so this is only needed for transactions... not normal updates? As in my threads, I don’t call `commit()` at the end.

Comment: If you don't call `commit`, any changes you make won't get persisted to the database. You should call `commit()` after you're done with your changes.